# Styling navbar: interaction between different styling settings

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having problems with styling my navigation bar, specifally the drop-down menu within the navigation bar. The two `li` elements below (the ones linking to "Profile" and "Edit profile" don't show up right. As you can see I have added the class `my-dropdown-item` in two different manners, both with the same result. The code for the navbar:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="header">
  <div class="top-nav">
      <ul class="nav1">
          <li class="hvr-bottom <%= 'active' if current_page?(root_path) %>"><%= link_to "Home".html_safe, root_path %></li>
          <li class="hvr-bottom <%= 'active' if current_page?(target_path) %>"><%= link_to "Target".html_safe, target_path %></li>

       # The dropdown menu #
       <li class="dropdown hvr-bottom" style="max-width:300px; width:auto;">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> "Drop-down Menu"</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user, html_options = {class: "my-dropdown-item"} %></li>
              <li class="my-dropdown-item"><%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
          </ul>
       </li>

      </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The result is that the font is shown in the color white, while it should be black. In my css file I have:

```
.my-dropdown-item {
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
}
```

Using the inspector I can see that the color is being overruled by the styling of `.top-nav ul li a` (so the font color specified by `my-dropdown-item` is lined through). The latter styling exists in a css file file1.css while `.my-dropdown-item` exists in file2.css. In `application.css` I have: `*= require file1` before the line `*= require file2`. So I don't understand why `.top-nav ul li a` overrules `.my-dropdown-item`. *Any idea how i can figure out the cause and what to do about it?*

Comment: In the the browser debug console, what do you see as the contributing class for the link where the font is misdisplayed? That will tell you what css is being applied.

Comment: @Val_Asensio, Isn't what you suggest the same as the inspector that I referred to in the OP? The css that is being applied is `.top-nav ul li a`, which is overruling `.my-dropdown-item` (as mentioned in the OP). Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I wasn't sure if that's what you meant by the inspector... Okay. I have an idea for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add override class in the link_to:**

```
  <%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_path(current_user), class:"my-dropdown-item" %>
```

**Add to CSS**

```
.my-dropdown-item {
  a {
  width: 100%;
  color: #000 !important;
  }
}
```

This might need some tweaking, let me know.

Comment: I tried this but with the same result. I also think it's somewhat similar as what I already had for profile: `<%= link_to "Profile", current_user, html_options = {class: "my-dropdown-item"} %>`. I tried different combinations: with the class specified for the `li` element and/or `link_to` element. And with in the css file `.my-dropdown-item {...` as well as `.my-dropdown-item { a { ...`. All with the same result: the css of `.top-nav ul li a` overwrites the css of `.my-dropdown-item`.

Comment: Ah, I initially forgot the `!important` part in the css file. Adding this solved it. Thanks!

Comment: !important is important for overrides.

Answer (score 0):

I supose that you're trying to put in black the link inside the `<li>` .

Your problem is that `.top-nav ul li a` is pointing to an `<a>` element and `.my-dropdown-item` is not pointing to this `<a>`.

It means that all inside `.my-dropdown-item` will be black but if you wrap the content into a  the new wrapper element will take the properties of this .

For a good performance you have to incluce the  and also the other previous class `.top-nav .my-dropdown-item a`.

I put you an example for better understanding.

```css
.top-nav ul li a {
  color: green
}

.top-nav .my-dropdown-item a{
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="header">
  <div class="top-nav">
      <ul class="nav1">
          <li class="hvr-bottom <%= 'active' if current_page?(root_path) %>"><%= link_to "Home".html_safe, root_path %></li>
          <li class="hvr-bottom <%= 'active' if current_page?(target_path) %>"><%= link_to "Target".html_safe, target_path %></li>

       # The dropdown menu #
       <li class="dropdown hvr-bottom" style="max-width:300px; width:auto;">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> "Drop-down Menu"</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a>Profile</a></li>
              <li class="my-dropdown-item"><a>Edit Profile</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>

      </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that it's not pointing to an element. I belief it does point to an element. The source code confirms this; if I look to the source code on the development server it has: 
`<li><a class="my-dropdown-item" href="/users/name">Profile</a></li>` and `<li class="my-dropdown-item"><a href="/users/name/edit">Edit profile</a></li>`

Comment: I think that the exaple is very self-explanatory of your problem

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. Rails converts the `link_to` method to an `<a>` element, and I belief `my-dropdown-item` *does* point to this `<a>` element.

Comment: Check the new example. your 'my-dropdown-item' is pointing to a '<li>' not to a' <a>'. The '<a>' element is inside you '.my-dropdown-item'

Comment: See my first comment:  `<li><a class="my-dropdown-item" href="/users/name">Profile</a></li> `